# How to handle kubernetes Ingress Rule with two backends

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I try to run my web application with two backend containers.

- / should be routed to the frontend container
- everything starting with /backend/ should go to the backend container.

So fare, so good, but now the css & js files from the /backend are not loaded because the files are referenced in the HTML file like "/bundles/css/style.css" and now ingress controller route this request to the frontend container instead of to the backend.

How can I fix this issue?

- Can I fix that with a smart Ingress rule?
- Do I need to update the app root of the backend container?

Here my Ingress resource

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 # for versions before 1.14 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: example
 namespace: example
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
   cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"

   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

spec:
 tls:
 - hosts:
   - www.example.ch
   secretName: tls-example.ch
 rules:
 - host: www.example.ch
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /backend(/|$)(.*)
       pathType: Prefix
       backend:
         service:
           name: example-backend-svc
           port:
             number: 8081
     - path: /
       pathType: Prefix
       backend:
         service:
           name: example-frontend-svc
           port:
             number: 8080
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add another path if all files are located in /bundles/* path.
I have given an example manifest file below.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 # for versions before 1.14 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: example
 namespace: example
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
   cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"

   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

spec:
 tls:
 - hosts:
   - www.example.ch
   secretName: tls-example.ch
 rules:
 - host: www.example.ch
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /backend(/|$)(.*)
       pathType: Prefix
       backend:
         service:
           name: example-backend-svc
           port:
             number: 8081
     - path: /bundles
       pathType: Prefix
       backend:
         service:
           name: example-backend-svc
           port:
             number: 8081
     - path: /
       pathType: Prefix
       backend:
         service:
           name: example-frontend-svc
           port:
             number: 8080
```