# Running 2 clusterIps with port 80 - but only one is accessible with Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have 2 applications running in Kubernetes cluster.

one with container port: 8081
second with container port: 8099

both have clusterIp with port 80.

both were checked outside the Kubernetes cluster with docker only: image is valid.

I run both of the microservices in Kubernetes, but only the second one is accessible with Ingress

in the first one I am getting the error: "502 bad gateway - ngnix".

1. what am I doing wrong ?
2. DI I defined correctly the ports in ingress resource ?
3. I know that both of the clusterIps have differnet ips and therefore they can both have the port - 80. is that correct? should I give the clusterIp different ports rather than 80?

these are my files:

App1:

```yaml
 apiVersion: apps/v1

 kind: Deployment

 metadata:
   name: app1-deployment
   namespace: nxtgen
   labels: 
    app: app1

 spec:

   replicas: 3
   selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
   
   template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app1
        image: artifactory-ik.com:6656/app1:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081       
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registrykey
---
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 

metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  type: ClusterIP

  selector:
    app: app1

  ports:
    # port - port exposed internally in the cluster
    # targetPort - the container port to send requests to
    - targetPort:  8081
      port: 80
```

App2:

```yaml
 apiVersion: apps/v1

 kind: Deployment

 metadata:
   name: app2
   namespace: nxtgen
   labels: 
    app: app2

 spec:

   replicas: 3
   selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app2
   
   template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app2
        image: artifactory-ik.com:6656/app2:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8099       
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registrykey
---
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 

metadata:
  name: app2
spec:
  type: ClusterIP

  selector:
    app: app2

  ports:
    # port - port exposed internally in the cluster
    # targetPort - the container port to send requests to
    - targetPort:  8099
      port: 80
```

Ingress resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1  
kind: Ingress
   
metadata:
   
  name: ingress-rules
  namespace: nxtgen
    
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules: 
    - host: nxthost.com
      http:  
        paths:  
          - path: /  
            pathType: Prefix  
            backend:  
              service: 
                name: app2
                port:
                  #same port of clusterIp
                   number: 80
          
          - path: /app2/info
            pathType: Prefix  
            backend:  
              service: 
                name: app2
                port:
                  #same port of clusterIp
                  number: 80

          - path: /app1/api/getInfo
            pathType: Prefix  
            backend:  
              service: 
                name: app1
                port:
                  #same port of clusterIp
                  number: 80
```

Comment: Your problem is the first path binding for `app2` on `/`, which is capturing all traffic and the following 'rules' aren't even being evaluated. Remove this and you'll get what you want. Btw, it might just be your example, but you probably want to use `/app1(/|$)(.*)` as the path instead (and similar for `app2`), along with a metadata annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2`

Comment: Software Engineer, can you post the correct ingress rules with my file? it still doesn't work for me...

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, nginx is usually smart enough to give the longer path precedence.

Comment: @TheFool - path length precedence... I've just confirmed that you're right about this, meaning that my assumption is wrong and therefore so is my answer. I'll remove it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, I still think your answer is somewhat relevant because you strip the path prefix. I think, that's the critical bit. Because the apps don't understand that they run at /app1 and /app2.  But with app2 we don't see it because it also matches /. For app1, that's not the case.

Comment: I think it's still readable even when deleted. Having the right answer for the wrong reason sort of sucks :) If I knew how nginx sorted paths I'd have probably thought about it some more and had more sound reasoning, but I jumped on the 'obvious' but wrong problem.

Comment: What I am saying is also a bit confused. Stripping the prefix is probably required but the traffic should still hit that app. Both should just give some sort of 404. So it doesn't really explain the 503. OP may have wrong ports specified. They long kind of random. Maybe they didn't realize that it won't change the port the container is actually listening on.

Comment: Hi @Ohad will this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67457651/how-to-handle-kubernetes-ingress-rule-with-two-backends) help?

Comment: I will check and update  
Dharani Dhar Golladasari

Comment: so I found the issue - one of my applications needed CPU and memory to be defined in the deployment file. once it was defined I was able to access it.